# c# parsing json: error reading json object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm having some issues with fetching json values in c#.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxn8e.png

Here is the code in question:

```
var json2 = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://fetch.json.url.here" + Input_Textbox.Text);
JObject o2 = JObject.Parse(json2);

string he_ident = (string)o2["he_ident"];
string le_ident = (string)o2["le_ident"];

Console.WriteLine(he_ident);
Console.WriteLine(le_ident);
```

Line 204 is: `JObject o2 = JObject.Parse(json2);`

The json is this: `[{"le_ident":"06L","he_ident":"24R"},{"le_ident":"06R","he_ident":"24L"},{"le_ident":"07L","he_ident":"25R"},{"le_ident":"07R","he_ident":"25L"}]`

I've also tried with just one set of le_ident and he_ident, such as `[{"le_ident":"06L","he_ident":"24R"}]` but it sill throws the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since it looks like you're using JSON.Net, have you tried just using `JsonConvert.Deserialize()` in an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, the cleanest approach to take is to define a class for the object signature you're expecting to take in:

```
class Entity {
    public he_ident { get;set; }
    public le_ident { get;set; }
}
```

Then just call `DeserializeObject()` into a collection:

```
var entities = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Entity>>(json2);
```

You should be able to access that then just like any C# object:

```
foreach(var entity in entities) {
    Console.WriteLine(entity.he_ident);
    Console.WriteLine(entity.le_ident);
}
```

This won't work if your JSON signature is dynamic though (or will be a bit tedious, as you'd have to define classes for each of your signatures).

But personally, I find that this approach does away with the muckiness that stuff like `ArrayList` had, and introduces strict typing into your code, which I find to generally lend itself to stronger, cleaner structure in a C# environment.

Answer (score 1):

You should use JArray instead of JObject for json arrays:

```
    var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(...);
    JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);
    string he_ident = (string)array[0]["he_ident"]; 
    string le_ident = (string)array[0]["le_ident"];
```

Answer (score 0):

That JSON is a list not a dictionary.

So what you need to do is this:

```
string he_ident = (string)(((ArrayList)o2)[0])["he_ident"];
```

(Or simply loop through the list)

The JSON data:

```
{"le_ident":"06L"}
```

Should work with the code you have there.

Comment: I gave it a shot, but it throws this error: `Cannot convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to 'System.Collections.ArrayList'`